# How to access Grafana/Prometheus only from local workstation?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I installed the Prometheus and Grafana into EKS cluster. I changed the ClusterIP to LoadBalancer. The URLs are accessible world wide.
http://a9042a504d25f4122b6aa52ed5e53b57-356305290.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com:9090
http://a7ebeb0da858f42328904560e7ce83c5-996403152.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com

I cannot access Prometheus and Grafana if I keep the service as ClusterIP.

Is it possible to limit accessibility to localhost only? As an example,

To access Kubernetes Dashboard from my local workstation I create a secure channel to my Kubernetes cluster. Run the following command:

kubectl proxy

Now access Dashboard at:

http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/.

Are there any similar approaches for Prometheus and Grafana?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you'd like to access Prometheus and Grafana in the same way you can keep using a ClusterIP service.
Then, whenever you want to access the server you can do so by running the following commands.
For Prometheus -
`kubectl port-forward service/<prometheus-service-name> 9090:9090`
For Grafana -
`kubectl port-forward service/<grafana-service-name> 8080:8080`

This will forward the remote service to your local 9090/8080 ports, and will allow you to access them from localhost.